Find $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and a subspace $\mathbb{W}$ such that $\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{T} \ne \{0\}$
The description of the problem is:
Let the subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ be:
$\mathbb{H} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + x_2 -x_3 + 2x_4 = 0\}$
$\mathbb{S} = \langle (1,-1,a,3) \rangle$ ,
$\mathbb{T} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + x_4 = 0, x_2 -3x_3 = 0\}$
Find $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and a subspace $\mathbb{W}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that:
$\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{T} \ne \{0\}$
Primary info I gathered:
the first condition $\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{H}$
implies a couple things:

$\mathbb{S} \subseteq \mathbb{H}$

$\mathbb{W} \subseteq \mathbb{H}$


and it implies that

$\dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{W}) = \dim(\mathbb{H})$

because the sum is direct
also, please remember the dimension theorem of finite vector spaces
$\dim(\mathbb{S} + \mathbb{W}) = \dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{W}) - \dim(\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{W})$
How I found that $a = 6$
I performed the intersection between $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{S}$, because from the condition
$\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{H}$ we know $\mathbb{S} \subseteq \mathbb{H}$
if you make the vector from $\mathbb{S}$ satisfy the equation of the plane $\mathbb{H}$
you get $a = 6$
$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (1,-1,a,3)$
$\mathbb{H} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + x_2 -x_3 + 2x_4 = 0\}$
$1 - 1 - a + 2 \cdot 3 = 0$
$-a + 6 = 0$
$a = 6$
Other info I gathered:
Since we know W and T have a nontrivial intersection
$\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{T} \ne \{0\}$
and we know that $\mathbb{W} \subseteq \mathbb{H}$
since $\mathbb{W}$ is entirely contained in $\mathbb{H}$,
Calculating $\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T}$
I solved the system of 3 equations and I got
$\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T} = \langle (2,3,1,-2) \rangle$.
Final ideas/thoughts of mine:
I believe that $\dim(\mathbb{W}) = 2$
but im not entirely convinced, so let me explain
$\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{H} \implies \dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{W}) = \dim(\mathbb{H})$
if a = 6, $\dim(\mathbb{S}) = 1$ and $\dim(\mathbb{H}) = 3$ then that must mean
$\dim(\mathbb{W}) = 2$ right? from dimension counting,
also, if $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{T} \ne \{0\}$ that must mean they have a nontrivial intersection, so at least one of the vectors, lets say
$\mathbb{W} = \langle \mathbf{w_1}, \mathbf{w_2} \rangle$
this must mean one of the vectors $\mathbf{w_1}$ or $\mathbf{w_2}$ or both are an element of $\mathbb{T}$, but as I said, since $\mathbb{W}$ is entirely contained in $\mathbb{H}$ we can use the only vector from $\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T} = \langle (2,3,1,-2) \rangle$ to be one of the $\mathbf{w_1}$ or $\mathbf{w_2}$ vectors (but since $\dim(\mathbb{H}\cap\mathbb{T}) = 1$ only one vector from $\mathbb{W}$ will satisfy the condition), lets say for example $\mathbf{w_2} \in \mathbb{H}\cap\mathbb{T}$
My question: How to find the other vector, the vector $\mathbf{w_1}$?
this vector $\mathbf{w_1}$ cannot be part of $\mathbb{S}$ and it needs to generate $\mathbb{H}$ (I am just saying in words what does the first condition mean)
$\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{H}$
If you read until here, thank you and I welcome comments and edits to this post.

Too long. What is your question?

I found one element for $\mathbb{W}$, but I am missing the other one , one of the elements from $\mathbb{W}$ I think can be the one from the basis of $\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T}$, also feel free to edit the post if its too long

+1. You are right, $\dim W=2$. But your basis of H and T are useless. To calculate $H\cap T$ (to which $W\cap T$ will indeed be equal), you could directly solve the corresponding system of 3 equations. I think $S^\perp$ and $S^\perp\cap H$ are also useless. All this could shorten your post, to make it more readable.

I agree with your comment, best way to calculate the intersection with $\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{T} \cap \mathbb{W}$ will be to solve the system of 3 equations, the problem is how do I know the equation of the plane of $\mathbb{W}$? I got the equation of $\mathbb{H}$ and the equation of the plane $\mathbb{T}$ but I am missing the equation of the plane of $\mathbb{W}$

My comment was not about calculating $H\cap T\cap W$, but about calculating $H\cap T$ by solving the system of 3 equations (one for H and two for T), notice it is a line, and conclude that $W\cap T$, which is a non-zero subspace of it, is equal to it.

As for your main problem, the solution $W$ is not unique. You already know a line $L$ contained in it. Choose any other line in $H$ which is not in the plane spanned by $L$ and $S$. SInce you allowed me, I shall remove the useless parts I mentionned.

after calculating the intersection $H \cap T$ by solving the system of 3 equations I got the same subspace $H \cap T = \langle (-2,-3,-1,2) \rangle$ which other line can I add to W? Like the other problem is that the sum of S with W needs to generate H, as you said I need to find a line in H which is not in the plane spanned by L and S, thank you for taking the time to edit the post by the way

You are almost done. The solution $\Bbb W$ is far from unique. $\Bbb W=\langle w_1,w_2\rangle$ with $w_2=(2,3,1,-2)$ and $w_1=$ any vector in $\Bbb H\setminus\langle w_2,w_3\rangle$, where $w_3=(1,-1,6,3)$ spans $\Bbb S$.
Some more calculations lead to $\langle w_2,w_3\rangle=\{(x,y,z,t)\in\Bbb R^4\mid 19x-11y-5z=0=7x-8y-5t\}$ and finally,
$\Bbb H\setminus\langle w_2,w_3\rangle=\{(-y+z-2t,y,z,t)\mid(y,z,t)\in\Bbb R^3, 15y-7z+19t\ne0\}$.
For instance, $w_1=(-1,1,0,0)$.
